Exporting TIFFs in GEE results in skinny vertical line of pixels
I have to do a task that involves exporting TIFFs, but unfortunately no matter what I've tried I just get these tiny files that look like a single, thin strand of black pixels when I put it into QGIS.
Here is my code:
var startYear = 2014;
var endYear = 2023;
var folderName = 'Nightlight';
var scale = 500; // Set scale in meters
var maxPixels = 1e13; // Increase maxPixels limit

// Define a region of interest (ROI)
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([[-180, -90], [180, 90]]);

// Loop through each year and month
for (var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) {
  for (var month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
    var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, 1);
    var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'month');

    // Filter dataset for the current month
    var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/ANNUAL_V21')
                    .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate));

    var nighttime = dataset.select('maximum'); //.median()? 

    // Define the export task
    var task = Export.image.toDrive({
      image: nighttime,
      description: 'Nighttime_' + year + '_' + month,
      folder: 'Nightlight',
      scale: scale,
      region: roi,
      fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
      crs: 'EPSG:4326',
      maxPixels: maxPixels
    });

    // Start the export task
    // task.start();
  }
}

Does anyone know why my exporting is wrong?
I can successfully view what I want to view in GEE, but the exporting to my drive just doesn't work at all.

Use a 6-point non-geodesic polygon to force it to span the globe (it's currently collapsing to a single line), and don't include the poles.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([-180, -88, 0, -88, 180, -88, 180, 88, 0, 88, -180, 88], null, false)


The Rectangular ROI is not suitable for exporting TIFFs because it covers the entire globe. When exporting, GEE will only export the pixels that intersect with the specified ROI, resulting in a thin vertical line of pixels. To resolve this issue, you can modify your ROI to cover a specific area of interest instead of the entire globe. For example, you can define a smaller rectangular ROI that encompasses a specific region or country:
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]);
